# How can I use array_replace inside foreach loop?

Tags: arrays, loops, symfony, search, replace

colums_arr:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => "productgroup"
  3 => "category"
]
```

fields:

```
    {#9767 ▼
  +"id": array:9 [▶]
  +"name": array:8 [▼
    "fieldName" => "name"
  ]
  +"productgroup": array:19 [▼
    "fieldName" => "productgroup"
    "mappedBy" => null
  ]
  +"category": array:19 [▼
    "fieldName" => "category"
    "mappedBy" => null
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is, whenever in `fields` mappedBy exists for the element, I want to add `name` to the value. So as a result `columns_arr` should look like this:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => "productgroup.name"
  3 => "category.name"
]
```

This is my approach:

```
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
      $MappedBy = isset($field['mappedBy']);
        if($MappedBy != true){
          $class_field = $field['fieldName'];
          $key = array_search($field['fieldName'],$input);
          $replace=array($key=>$class_field.".name");
          $columns_arr = (array_replace($input,$replace));
      }
    }
```

The problem is, that my result is now:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => "productgroup"
  3 => "category.name"
]
```

Why is `name` not added to `productgroup`?

Comment: `$columns_arr[] = (array_replace($input,$replace));`

Comment: @Fabian Your suggestion gives me the output `array:6 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => "productgroup"
  3 => "category"
  4 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "id"
    1 => "name"
    2 => "productgroup.name"
    3 => "category"
  ]
  5 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "id"
    1 => "name"
    2 => "productgroup"
    3 => "category.name"
  ]
]`

Comment: Look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't really answer your question, it's a bit unclear what you're doing and where your values are coming from etc. so I tried to rebuild your arrays and this is what I got without using array_search:

```
<?php

$columns = array(0 => "id", 1 => "name", 2 => "productgroup", 3 => "category");

$fields = array("id" => 9, "name" => array("fieldName" => "name"), "productgroup" => array("fieldName" => "productgroup", "mappedBy" => null), "category" => array("fieldname" => "category", "mappedBy" => null));
foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
    if($key !== "id" && $key !== "name"){
        if(!isset($field['mappedBy'])){
            foreach($columns as $ckey => $column){
                if($column === $key){
                    $columns[$ckey] = $column.".name";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($columns);
```

var_dump outputs:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "id" [1]=> string(4) "name" [2]=> string(17) "productgroup.name" [3]=> string(13) "category.name" }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
    $MappedBy = isset($field['mappedBy']);
      if($MappedBy != true){
        $columns_arr[$key] = $field['fieldName'].".name";
    }
  }
```

You need to overwrite the correct key of your array like this.

Comment: I tested. The output is: `array:4 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "id"
    1 => "name"
    2 => "productgroup.name"
    3 => "category"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "id"
    1 => "name"
    2 => "productgroup"
    3 => "category.name"
  ]
]`

Comment: Now the output is:`array:6 [▼
  0 => "id"
  1 => "name"
  2 => "productgroup"
  3 => "category"
  "productgroup" => "productgroup.name"
  "category" => "category.name"
]`

Comment: What is `$input` ?

Comment: $input = array_keys($columns);

Comment: It is so difficult I simply tried to make this test `foreach ($fields as $field) {

      $columns_arr[array_search($field, $columns_arr)] = 'test';

    }` where I expect that all value will become `test`. But only `id` is replaced...